# Finding closest numbers within two arrays

Tags: c++, algorithm, difference

I have to find closest numbers within two arrays and shows their difference. I am using a loop for that but it takes too much time. Do you know any way to make that algorithm faster?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>

using namespace std;

long long int red, yellow, minimum = 1000000000, difference = 0;
long long int TC[100001], ZT[100001];

int main()
{
    scanf("%d", &red);
    for (int y = 0; y < red; ++y)
    {
        scanf("%d", &TC[y]);
    }

    scanf("%d", &yellow);
    for (int yy = 0; yy < yellow; ++yy)
    {
        scanf("%d", &ZT[yy]);
    }

    for (int yyy = 0; yyy < red; ++yyy)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < yellow; ++i)
        {
            difference = abs(TC[yyy] - ZT[i]);
            if (difference == 0)
            {
                minimum = 0;
                break;
            }
            else if (difference < minimum)
                minimum = difference;
        }
    }
    printf("%d \n", minimum);
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing working code, which should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You wouldn't have to run loops `red*yellow` times if `TC` and `ZT` were ordered. You can optimize working on that.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg, just generally asking, many good questions that are asked with algorithm tag on SO go like 'I am aware of the simple O (N^2) solution but I want more efficient one'. Are such questions counted as off-topic for SO?

Comment: @user1990169 No they are not, but such questions will most likely get the question if the poster had actually done some measurement and profiling to see if that's really the bottle-neck, and will be reminded that there is a tradeoff (as there always is) between simplicity and portability (using the standard functions) versus complexity and potential bugs and possible incompatibilities between platforms.

Comment: This is so about programming, should never be closed !

Comment: @EricWang I’d leave it closed, only the reason is not correct. The part _“Do you know any way…”_ is making the question too broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This shoud be O(nlgn):

```
sort two lists
let i = 0, j = 0, minval = abs(list1[0] - list2[0])
as long as both lists have more items:
  minval = min(minval, abs(list1[i] - list2[j])
  if abs(list1[i + 1] - list2[j]) < abs(list1[i] - list2[j + 1])
     increment i
  else increment j
```

Comment: How do you solve: as long as both lists have more items?

Comment: `i < list1.size() && j < list2.size()`

Comment: How do you get list1[i + 1] when i = list1.size() - 1 ?

Comment: I don't think it is that hard to work out the edge case.

Answer (score 1):

If you sort them, you can optimize algorithm to run much faster. When your both arrays are sorted, you can check one by one and compare them less than your current algorithm. Because you'll skip some of them, since you know they are sorted.

By the way, since you get the numbers from user, I suggest you to put numbers in sorted. Every time user enters a number, put the number in a place where numbers after it are bigger than it and numbers before it are less than it. To do such a thing, maybe using linked list is better idea (or easier).

Comment: using a linked list of long longs is much slower than using a vector. Vector has  random access iterators which makes sorting faster, copying is not as bad as you think because its just a block copy where as list needs to allocate every node and is not in contiguous memory so lots of cache misses! List may be theoretically less complexity but NOT faster on modern architecture because of the way caches work.